# SQL Insert into giving Invalid column error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to execute the following SQL but gives invalid column "open" etc for all columns

```
    insert into t ("Date","assignee","pkey","open","In Progress","Awaiting  Release","Referred")
select date, assignee,pkey,open,[In Progress],[Awaiting Release],[referred] from (
SELECT Cast(Getdate() AS DATE) AS Date, 
       pname                   AS Status, 
       assignee, 
       pkey 
FROM   s JI, 
       k JS 
WHERE  JI.issuestatus = JS.id 
       AND JI.issuetype IN ( 21, 4 ) 
       AND JS.pname IN( 'Open', 'In Progress', 'Awaiting Release', 'Referred' ))as source
    PIVOT
    (count([Status])
    FOR [status] in ([Open],[In Progress],[Awaiting Release],[Referred])) as pvt
```

Comment: Try escaping it as [Open]

Comment: Thanks I added the escape character , however this SQL statement is  added at the end of a SQL file which has many other statements . All the other above it gets execeuted , however this alone doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPEN is a command so you need to put square brackets around it to highlight it is a field

```
 insert into t ("Date","assignee","pkey","open","In Progress","Awaiting  Release","Referred")
select date, assignee,pkey,[open],[In Progress],[Awaiting Release],[referred] from (
SELECT Cast(Getdate() AS DATE) AS Date, 
       pname                   AS Status, 
       assignee, 
       pkey 
FROM   s JI, 
       k JS 
WHERE  JI.issuestatus = JS.id 
       AND JI.issuetype IN ( 21, 4 ) 
       AND JS.pname IN( 'Open', 'In Progress', 'Awaiting Release', 'Referred' ))as source
    PIVOT
    (count([Status])
    FOR [status] in ([Open],[In Progress],[Awaiting Release],[Referred])) as pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but updating the first statement as below worked

```
insert into t ([Date],[assignee],[pkey],[open],[In Progress],[Awaiting  Release],[Referred])
```